# How to count results from a sub query with an IIf Function

Tags: sql

The below query works perfectly to provide a list of agents for whom a review has been 'Completed' or 'Not Completed' - Now what I want to do is simply COUNT the total of the 'Completed' reviews.

```
SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm, IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') As Status FROM
    (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm FROM Dbo.vEmpView WHERE MgrName = 'Starr, Ringo' GROUP BY Assoc_ID, 
     Full_Nm) A
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AssocID, AssocName  FROM Tri.FacetoFace WHERE EnteredBy = 'Starr, Ringo' AND DateOfReview 
     >'1/31/2020' GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName) B
        ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID
GROUP BY A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm, B.AssocID, B.AssocName
ORDER BY Status
```

Below is my latest attempt to resolve this but It's throwing an Incorrect Syntax Error near ')'. I've tried a WHERE and a GROUP BY in various iterations - still throws an error.
Thank You all for any help

```
Select Count(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Boo FROM

    (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm, IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') As Status FROM
        (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm FROM Dbo.vEmpView WHERE MgrName = 'Starr, Ringo' GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm) A
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT AssocID, AssocName  FROM Tri.FacetoFace WHERE EnteredBy = 'Starr, Ringo' AND DateOfReview >'1/31/2020' GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName) B
        ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID)
```

Comment: Change `Count(...)` to `Sum(...)`. The `Count` function just check whether a value is returned, and doesn't care whether that value is 0 or 1.

Comment: Hey Josh ~ Thank you for chiming in - So I changed COUNT to SUM and it is still throwing the Syntax error near ')'... There are no red squigs in the code - I feel as though there should be a GROUP BY clause - but when I do GROUP BY Boo I get a invalid column name

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Quick update: I added parens after WHEN and after 'Completed' in the SUM (CASE statement - still same error

Comment: SOLVED: I forgot to alias the new SELECT result set - This did the trick:

`SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (Status = 'Completed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Boo FROM

    (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm, IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') As Status FROM
        (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm FROM Dbo.vEmpView WHERE MgrName = 'Starr, Ringo' GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm) A
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT AssocID, AssocName  FROM Tri.FacetoFace WHERE EnteredBy = 'Starr, Ringo' AND DateOfReview >'1/31/2020' GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName) B
        ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID) C`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (Status = 'Completed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Boo FROM (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm, IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') As Status FROM (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm FROM Dbo.vEmpView WHERE MgrName = 'Starr, Ringo' GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT AssocID, AssocName FROM Tri.FacetoFace WHERE EnteredBy = 'Starr, Ringo' AND DateOfReview >'1/31/2020' GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName) B ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID) C
```